# How can I declare angularjs in web worker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-worker

I have created a webworker like

```
new Worker('sample.js')
```

in  sample.js

```
angular.module('appname').directive('directivename',function()
{});
```

I am getting the angular not defined error.

Can I define my web worker in angular?

Comment: why would you want to do this? there is no `window` object in a web worker,  no html, angular would not work since there is no html to parse.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it the other way round. Define your Worker inside angular.

```
angular.module('appname').directive('directivename',function(){
  new Worker('yourWorkerJs.js');
});
```

Also IMHO, I do not understand why you would want a worker for directive? Services are the most sensible place to define worker.